# Perl, ClamAV, scan a stream for viruses

Tags: perl, sockets, antivirus, antivirus-integration

I have a perl app. I need to scan some files for viruses .

I can use the ClamAV and the module File::Scan::ClamAV .
It works if i need to scan some file stored on disk or if a file is loaded to a memory (to some variable).

But my app doesn't have full file. It only has an input stream (opened socket). It reads from this socket and writes to other output stream.

Can i pass somehow the stream through ClamAV? Like to forward my input stream to clamav and read data back from it but at the end to get some result of scanning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module [ClamAV::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/ClamAV::Client) seems to provide a means to scan streams with the [`scan_stream` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/ClamAV::Client#scan_stream($handle):-RETURNS-SCALAR;-THROWS-ClamAV::Client::Error).

Here's how I think that works puzzled together from the documentation:

```
use ClamAV::Client;

# Try using socket options from clamd.conf, or use default socket:
my $scanner = ClamAV::Client->new();

# Scan a stream, i.e. read from an I/O handle:
my $result = $scanner->scan_stream($handle);

# $result is the name of a virus signature, or undef
die "infected" if $result;
```

Note that I have not tried it (yet).

Comment: I cannot figure out where my ClamAV is listening. My example above is for the default socket, but that doesn't work for me. I don't have it configured on TCP, and I don't want to break it. So no test, sorry.

Comment: I am going to try it.

Comment: this works. but in my case i had to set socket_name     => '/var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock'  in a client constructor